# How to set the SELECTED property of dropdown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am sending the index number of dropdown's options that users selects from index. Now want to select that specific option as 'selected' on another view. How to make it using jQuery?

```
$('#book_selection').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('#book_selection').selectedIndex = 1;
```

but its not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prop()` method, setting `selectedIndex` to a jQuery object practically does nothing. As of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties `prop` method should be used instead of `attr` method:

```
$('#book_selection').prop("disabled", true)
                    .prop('selectedIndex', 1);
```

Alternatives:

```
// Getting the DOM element object using bracket notation and `.get()` method
$('#book_selection')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
$('#book_selection').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.prop()` for setting the properties, By the way you are in need to set the value by using index, so in that case `.eq(index)` will help you.

Try,

```
$('#book_selection option').eq(1).prop('selected',true);
```